# Mouse cursor included when taking screenshots with imageio or pyautogui?

Tags: python, pyautogui, python-imageio

How is it possible to have the **mouse cursor included when taking screenshots** with:

```
imageio.imread('<screen>')
```

or

```
pyautogui.screenshot(region=(0,0,300,300))
```

?

`imread` does not seem to offer such `cursor` a parameter.

The goal is finally to record screen at ~ 20 fps, to do a screencast recorder.

Answer (score 0):

You may try `Alt-PrintScreen` and have your cursor around, makes a nice picture:

[image]

Comment: I need to do `imageio.imread('<screen>')` 20 times per second in order to program a screen cast recorder, so this option would not work here.

Comment: @Basj you may want to explicitly say about screen cast @ 20fps in the original question